# How to avoiding nullchar converted to 0?

Tags: c++, atoi, null-character

I have a char array that is filled with `{'1','0','0','0'}` for example, I apply `atoi()` on this array it returns `1000` which is `true`, however after I reset the array elements to null char `'\0'` and refill the array with `50` and apply `atoi()` again it doesn't output `50` but `5000`.

```
char number[10]={};
num = atoi(number);
customer[i].balance = customer[i].balance + num;
cout<<"I added the deposit"<<endl;
cout<<customer[i].balance<<endl;
num = 0;
for (int r=0; r<strlen(number); r++)
 {
   number[r]='\0';
 }
```

Comment: That doesn't actually set all elements of the array to `'\0'`.

Comment: Thank you,that is what i found when i researched about it, do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: Ideas for what? How to zero out an array? [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) is an option.

Comment: `char number[10] = {};` already zero-initalizes the array, and then `num = atoi(number);` tries to convert that array (which represents an empty string) to a number. I don't see what you're trying to do here.

Comment: this will reset the array to zeros, what i need is to clear the array (making it empty again)

Comment: The array can't be "empty". You array of 10 elements will always have 10 elements in it.

Comment: char number[10]={}; i just show my declaration to the array, there is other segment of code which fills the array with values.

Comment: You have an array of 10 `int`s, and `int`s always have a value (even if it's 0). What is it you want to be "empty"?

Comment: After you have done `number[0] = '\0';`, what do you think `strlen(number)` is?

Comment: strlen(number) will be equal to the number of elements inside the array or always 10 ?

Comment: `strlen(number)` is the number of characters before the first null character. Where is the first null character after you set `number[0] = '\0'`?

Comment: i understood part of the problem now, how can i prevent atoi from reading '\0' in the array as 0 i have tried to write an atoi function other than atoi() and make it terminate when it reads '\0' in the array and the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: You have not understood the problem. `atoi` does not read `'\0'` as `0`. The problem is that you only think you set all array elements to `'\0'`, but you actually don't, so there are real `0`s left in the array which `atoi` reads.

Comment: @AmrBumadian `atoi` is not the problem. The problem is that your loop only replaces the first character - the other `'0'`s are still there.

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you i will solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is the condition in the for-loop. That condition is **fully** evaluated after every iteration. That means not just the `r<` part, but also the `strlen(number)` part. This is generally a bad idea - `strlen` must check the whole sting to find the first `\0`. In very exceptional situations that might make sense, but here it does not. You want to use the original, unmodified string length.

If you understand strings a bit better, you might realize that you don't need `r` at all. You can simply set characters to `\0` until you find one that's already `\0`.